# Angular push to Django for user login form error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)"

Tags: javascript, json, django, angular

I'm assuming that the < is because it's returning a HTML or XML response.

This is my login part where it's failing.

```
  public login(user) {
    this.http.post('/api-token-auth/', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('login success', data);
        this.updateData(data['token']);
      },
      err => {
        console.error('login error', err);
        this.errors = err['error'];
      }
    );
```

`user` returns {username: "user", password: "password"}

`JSON.stringify(user)` returns {"username":"user", "password":"pass"}

`this.httpOptions` returns {headers: HttpHeaders} with array content-type application/json

console is returning the err 'login error' and I don't know why

This is the error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttp…, text: "↵↵<!doctype html>↵<html>↵<head>↵    <base href="/"…s"></script>↵</body>↵</html>↵                    "}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/"
```

note: I temporarily disabled csrf middleware because I was running into an issue there as well, not sure if related.

httpOption used for making API calls, in the same file as above snippet

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

public httpOptions: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  };
}
```

Comment: couple of questions. Is django api running on port 8000 ?on what port you are running angular? Can you post the `this.httpOptions` too?

Comment: @KiraAG Django is on port 8000, angular is `ng build` and deployed in Django static directory. I added the httpOption in the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The urlpatterns was redirecting the page before it got the chance to obtain token.
Before:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('first.urls'),
    path(r'api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path(r'api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token))
```

After:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token),
    path(r'api-token-refresh/', refresh_jwt_token),
    url(r'^', include('first.urls'))
```